# como puedo hacer una función numero mayor en DEV C++?

Tags: funciones

[image: QUISIERA HACER LO MISMO QUE EN LA IMAGEN......WDWEDFW]4RGVGRYJYSYT5J7NYJK57WKSY57KL56KK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void mayor(int a, int b){
    if(a > b)
        std::cout << a << " es mayor que " << b << '\n';
    else if(b > a)
        std::cout << b << " es mayor que " << a << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "los numeros son identicos\n";
}
```